# Link to Approvals screen in Salesforce mobile

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

I'm trying to create a link in an outgoing email to the 'Approvals' screen in the Salesforce mobile app. It's the screen you get when you tap 'Approvals' in the menu. Does anyone know what URL I should use? (keeping in mind that Gmail does not allow non-http hyperlinks)

[image]